# How can you tell if GStreamer plugins are installed correctly

Tags: gstreamer

I've installed GStreamer plugins for Fedora 14 using yum.  However, when running a qt-phonon application with the GStreamer backend, I get the error

> Warning: You do not seem to have the base GStreamer plugins installed.
>             All audio and video support has been disabled

Is there a good baseline test to determine if this is a Phonon problem?  Does anybody know where yum installs the GStreamer plugins and how GStreamer resolves plugins?

Comment: `gst-inspect` maybe? Should let you know which plugins are installs.

Comment: Hmm gst-inspect is showing I have valid plugins.  I guess the better question is why am I getting that warning?

Comment: @derobert thanks for that.  grepping for gst-plugins-base only yields uridecodebin and decodebin2.  I know that's not right ... It also throws GStreamer-Critical GST_IS_ELEMENT failed :(

Answer (score 0):

Install [RPM Fusion repos](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration)

Then install `phonon`'s `vlc` backend:

```
su -c 'yum install phonon-backend-vlc'
```

Remove the `gstreamer` backend:

```
su -c 'yum erase phonon-backend-gstreamer'
```

Comment: I have the Xine backend working but I want to use the gstreamer backend. I'm testing an application that runs on an embedded product that doesn't have vlc.